# Importing saved HTML file in Pandas as DataFrame instead of a dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table saved offline into HTML format. I wish to import it in Pandas and work on it. But pandas imports it as Dict instead of dataframe. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib

option_table = pd.read_html("C:/Users/home-pc/Desktop/operator.html")
print(option_table[['Circle name', 'Code']])
```

Here is the HTML table which i have saved offline on my computer:[enter link description here](https://sinuateainudog.htmlpasta.com/)

The error I get when I run my code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\home-pc\Desktop\offline.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(option_table[['Circle name', 'Code']])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

How can I import my offline HTML page as a dataframe instead of a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's getting imported as a one-element list. Indexing that first element and then casting it as a `DataFrame` worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib

option_table = pd.read_html("https://sinuateainudog.htmlpasta.com/")
option_table_df = pd.DataFrame(option_table[0])
print(option_table_df[['Circle name', 'Code']])
```